# Best 32 bit electronics for delta?

Tags: electronics, delta

I'm looking to update my Delta printer's electronics from 8-bit to 32-bit.

So I checked Marlin and found out that they working on a project they call it Re-ARM and as far as I can tell they will support few chip-sets - I can't remember which one, so until when that happens I need to use something else but what?

I need it to be open source but the [Smoothieboard](https://reprap.org/wiki/Smoothieboard) (original one) is too expensive. I saw MKS SBASE but they are closed-source. There is also the [MKS GEN version of it](https://reprap.org/wiki/MKS_GEN) but again it uses an ATmega2560. Is there solution for now for my problem until 32-bit Marlin reaches test phase ?

Comment: I think this question is too subjective. Please do not ask questions that are [primarily opinion-based](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Looking past the possibility of multiple, opinion-based answers, the scope for which the user is asking for is looking **any** solution. So, multiple (even opinion-based) answers are acceptable for the user in this situation.

Comment: I believe MKS SBASE is open source as it runs smoothie board firmware, or at least it can. I am running one on a delta and it works well for my purposes. But you can get similar results with the 8bit AVR marlin boards.

Comment: @hilo90mhz What you saying is that MKS SBASE can run genuine smoothie firmware right ?

Comment: I believe so, but I would research it more as I could be mistaken and it is some modified version of the smoothie firmware, it has been a little time since mine was setup.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved your problem at all? If so, would you like to post an answer? If not, could you update your question, with more information?

Answer (score 2):

*Note that I am not stating this as the best 32 bit solution, as that is too subjective. Although you might want to read [Recommendations for a good 32 bit microprocessor to run Marlin](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/3851), which I cover in [On which board can 32 bit Marlin run?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/on-which-board-can-32-bit-marlin-run#6494)*

---

So, to clarify, yes, while the [MKS-BASE](https://reprap.org/wiki/MKS_BASE_1.0) is based on the 8 bit ATmega2560, the [MKS-SBASE](https://reprap.org/wiki/Sbase) is powered by 32 bit ARM, 100M Cortex-MS MCU-LPC1768.

Anyway, SmoothieWare can indeed run on MKS-SBASE. There is an *extensive* guide on [Instructables - Configuring MKS SBASE V1.X 32-bit controller basics and into to SmoothieWare.](https://www.instructables.com/id/Configuring-MKS-Sbase-V12-32-bit-Controller-Basics/)

You first need the [drivers](https://github.com/makerbase-mks/MKS-SBASE/tree/master/English/Driver) (for Windows). Plug in the MKS-SBASE board and then install the driver.

> **Connecting USB**
>
> Plug in USB to the board and look at the LEDs at the upper left
>   corner.  Immediately the `D7` led lights up. After a bit `D1` also
>   starts lightning while `D2` and `D3` blinks rapidly.
>
> Open device manager and update drivers for the new Smoothie/Serial USB
>   device with the signed drivers you just downloaded from Github located
>   in the easy to find folder:
>   `\MKS-SBASE\MKS-SBASE\Driver\smoothieware-windows-signeddriver-v1.0`

Then to install the firmware:

> **Installing firmware**
>
> 1. Firmware from MKS are just and old copy of Smoothieware, so we always just want to use the newest version from Smoothieware.
>
>    1. In other words: **always use firmware from Smoothieware**.
>    2. If you can't find `config.txt` file from original Smoothieware, just use the one from MKS.
> 2. Download official firmware from Smoothieware's [firmware page](http://triffid-hunter.no-ip.info/Smoothie.html) which is a subpage on their own [Github page](https://github.com/Smoothieware/Smoothieware) (you might want to
>      download their full Github repository (folder) in order to find their
>      config.txt file)
>
>    1. Start by using the Stable version. When everything is working fine, you can use the Nightly version instead. It is the newest
>         version, but not fully tested yet, and considered as beta/test.
> 3. Insert the SD Card into the MKS Sbase board and plug in the USB Cable. Your SD Card is now going to show in your file-Explorer.
>
>    1. If not, you need to make sure you have the Drivers installed.
> 4. If you can't find the `config.txt` file from Smoothieware, just locate the `config.txt` in `\MKS
>      Sbase\MKS-SBASE-master\MKSSBase-firmware` and copy it to your SD Card.
>
>    1. Smoothieware suggest disabling auto-Mount on the SD when connecting to USB. Especially when using a Mac, as OSX tends to do
>         funky stuff at strange times.
>    2. I have changed nothing on my Win10. And nothing bad has happened the past year.
> 5. The D7 lights up, shortly after D1 follows. D2, D3, D4 blinks and then D4 turns steady while D2 and D3 continues blinking.
>
>    1. At this point, the `firmware.bin` had changed to `firmware.cur` file on the SD card
> 6. After successful updated, the file name will turn into firmware.cur.
>
> **Changing or Updating firmware**
>
> Just delete the `firmware.cur` file from your SD, or rename to
>   `firmware.cur.old` or similar, and copy on the new `firmware.bin` file
>   to your SD. Powercycle your printer (also unplug USB) and you can see
>   your new `firmware.cur` file on your SD card.
>
> **Note:** After making any changes to your `config.txt` file in the future, you need to power-cycle your controller, meaning disconnect
>   both power (if in use) and USB. You can send a reset command, but only
>   through true terminal use and not through Printrun/Pronterface or
>   similar.

The guide, as stated above is extremely detailed, and goes on to explain all of the other aspects. The contents are as follows:

> **Table Of Contents:**
>
> 1. Connect and install
>
>    1. Connecting USB
>    2. Installing firmware
> 2. Configuring Smoothieware compared to Marlin
> 3. Obvious difference from Marlin
>
>    1. Less obvious differneces
>    2. Firmware and Config file(s)
>    3. Configuring firmware
>    4. Comments
> 4. Firmware Step 1: Default feed rate
>
>    1. 1/32 Multistepping
>    2. Connecting Motors
>    3. External Motor Controllers
> 5. Firmware Step 2: Cartesian axis speed limits, pins and current
>
>    1. Pins
>    2. Current
> 6. Firmware Step 3: LCD, SD and Extruder
>
>    1. LCD and SD
>    2. Extruder Setup
>    3. Delta driver current
> 7. Firmware Step 4: Hotend temperature control configuration
>
>    1. Thermistor Type
>    2. PID Tuning
>    3. Hotend Thermistor - Physical Layout
>    4. Hotend Heater Pins - Physical Layout
> 8. Firmware Step 5: Heated bed temperature control configuration
>
>    1. Thermistor Type
>    2. Temperature Control Bed BANG-BANG
>    3. Heated bed thermistor - Physical Layout
>    4. Heated bed heater pins - Physical Layout
> 9. Firmware Step 6: Configuring Endstops
>
>    1. Homing direction
>    2. Disable unused endstops
>    3. Define axes size
>    4. Reversing endstop output
>    5. Fast and slow homing rates
> 10. Firmware step 7: Network Settings
> 11. Step 8: What's next?
>
>     1. More advanced setup?
>     2. Using Switches

As there is way to much to cover here, please visit the [Instructables page](https://www.instructables.com/id/Configuring-MKS-Sbase-V12-32-bit-Controller-Basics/) for the complete guide, in order to complete the configuration.