# On which board can 32 bit Marlin run?

Tags: marlin

Does anyone know on which board that can be bought today is possible to run current Marlin x32 ?

Comment: Have a look at the [platformio.ini](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/platformio.ini) file - it's got the list of compatible boards/processors

Comment: @ZacFaragher Make an answer?

Comment: There is none at this time.  you can use repetier or some other firmware.  there is a marlin for due but the code base is a mess.

Comment: Tnx @EricKelly probably I will get Duet WiFi

Comment: Hi, is this a duplicate of [Best 32 bit electronics for delta?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/best-32-bit-electronics-for-delta)

Comment: Hi, have you resolved your problem at all? If so, would you like to post an answer? If not, could you update your question, with more information?

Answer (score 4):

The  [`platformio.ini`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/platformio.ini) file, given in [Zac's comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/on-which-board-32-bit-marlin-can-run#comment6505_4655), does not seem to list all of the boards supported.

However, [The Marlin 2.0 32-bit thread](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/7076) appears to have a table that is much more complete (at the time of writing):

```
Board                           MCU         State            To-Do
RAMPS, etc.                  Arduino AVR    good  
Due, RAMPS FD (v2.A!), etc.  SAM3X8E        good  
Archim 1.0                   SAM3X8E        ❓unknown    Only US$170!
Archim 2.0                   SAM3X8E        beta       needs confirmation
Re-ARM                       LPC1768        beta       NEOPIXEL_LED,M100,ENDSTOP_INTERRUPTS,Tones,etc.
MKS-SBASE                    LPC1768        beta       NEOPIXEL_LED,M100,Tones, etc.
Smoothieboard                LPC1769        beta       NEOPIXEL_LED,M100,Tones, etc.
Azteeg X5 GT                 LPC1769        beta       NEOPIXEL_LED,M100,Tones, etc.
Cohesion3D Remix             LPC1769        beta       NEOPIXEL_LED,M100,Tones, etc.
Selena Compact               LPC1768        beta       NEOPIXEL_LED,M100,Tones, etc.
Malyan M200                 STM32F103C8     beta       EMERGENCY_PARSER,NEOPIXEL_LED, etc.
Borg                        STM32F765ZGT6   ⚠️beta       EMERGENCY_PARSER,NEOPIXEL_LED, etc.
Chitu3D V3.9                STM32F103ZET6   alpha      EMERGENCY_PARSER,NEOPIXEL_LED, LCD, SDCard, MAX6675, etc.
Teensy 3.5                  MK64FX          alpha      (need shields)
Teensy 3.6                  MK66FX          alpha      (need shields)
STEVAL-3DP001V1             STM32F401VE     alpha      (need boards)
```

From [[Question] Most promising 32 Bit Platform for Marlin 2.x](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/9222)

> The reference platform IS Re-Arm with a RAMPS shield. You can find instructions for both obtaining it and getting setup with it at [#7076](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/7076)

It appears the you have to use the *bugfix* branch:

> Right now, there are two branches. Bugfix-v1.1.x and Bugfix-v2.0.0. They are almost identical from a feature set perspective. But Bugfix-v2.0.0 is modified to have a hierarchical file layout. That was needed to clean up the code and to support 32-bit.
>
> The AVR code is fully debugged and working in both branches. The 32-bit code only exists (and works) in the Bugfix-v2.0.0 branch. And while the code does work... And some people are using it to print, it isn't entirely painless to get to that point.

You may also want to read [Recommendations for a good 32 bit microprocessor to run Marlin](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/3851). To list a few examples:

- Atmel ATSAM3x8e on the Due board
- Anyhow, there are a lot of 32bit Controller. Take a look at mbed.org for example.
  You can use the arm-none-eabi-xxx for STM32, LPC, also the Arduino Due use it
- Duet board (now called DuetWifi) is available for pre-order. It has a 120MHz Cortex M4 with hardware FPU
- AZSMZ ARM 32bit controller board
- RedBear: https://redbearlab.github.io/arduino/package_redbear_index.json

  - RedBear Duo (Cortex-M3, WiFi + BLE)
  - RedBear discussion forum
- Konekt Dash/DashPro (Official): http://downloads.konekt.io/arduino/package_konekt_index.json

  - Cortex M4-based global cellular dev kits, support for all board variants, support for USB and over-the-air programming straight from within Arduino IDE

Another link that might be useful is [Unofficial list of 3rd party boards support urls](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Unofficial-list-of-3rd-party-boards-support-urls), although not all of these are 32 bit.